# How to update a column value in swt?

Tags: java, swt

I'm new to JAVA SWT, but however I managed to create a table and populate values in to the table using the contentProvider and labelProvider.

Now I want to update the status column value from not processed -->in progress-->complete based on the response returned by the server.

How can I achieve this ?

While I was googling I found **display.syncExec**. But when I tried this I'm getting **NullPointerException**.

```
public Thread refresh( final InvoiceShadow shadow, final GenericCommunicationResponse response, final List shadowList){

    return new Thread() {

    public void run() {

            display.syncExec( new Runnable() {

                public void run() {                     
                    refreshStatus( shadow, response,shadowList );
                }
            });         
        }
    };
}

public void refreshStatus( InvoiceShadow shadow, GenericCommunicationResponse response, List shadowList ){

    tableViewer.setInput(shadowList);

    if(response.isSuccess()){

        shadow.setStatus(new InvoiceStatusType("Varianced"));

    } else {
        shadow.setStatus(new InvoiceStatusType("NotVarianced"));        
    }

    tableViewer.refresh();
}
```

Please help me in this and please let me know if there is any other way to update the column.

Comment: Where is `display` coming from? Where do you get the null pointer exception?

Comment: I understood why I was getting null. That is been resolved. however I'm facing one more problem , the code execution is getting stuck at display.syncExec( new Runnable() .. I'm not getting any exception or error.

Comment: SyncExec waits until the main SWT UI thread is idle. If you are doing something that runs for a long time in the UI thread it will hang. Long running code must be in a non-UI thread.

Comment: I'm sorry this might be very basic thing to ask , what do you mean by that? when you say code must be in a non-UI thread- how do I achieve this ?